# Why Function "if ProcessExist" Don't Work in Others Computers

Tags: autoit

I'm trying to execute an IF ProcessExist.

in my win 10 64bit computer it works, but when i execute in other PC with win 7 or even with win 10. It do not execute.

```
 #AutoIt3Wrapper_UseX64=N
    If ProcessExists ("program.exe") Then
MsgBox ("", "Hold", "Test", 10)
    Exit
    Else
        #RequireAdmin
    Run(@ComSpec & " /c " & "C:\folder\file.bat", "", @SW_HIDE)
        EndIf
```

Keep getting as if program.exe exist, but it's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#RequireAdmin must be on the very top of your script.
```

I assume it's not working when you compile the executable. It's probably called program.exe and it's finding its own process.

As for the Singleton see [this](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/libfunctions/_Singleton.htm):

```
_Singleton ( $sOccurrenceName [, $iFlag = 0] )
Enforce a design paradigm where only one instance of the script may be running
```

Example

```
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>

If _Singleton("test", 1) = 0 Then
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Warning", "An occurrence of test is already running")
    Exit
EndIf
MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "OK", "the first occurrence of test is running")
```

Comment: **I assume it's not working when you compile the executable. It's probably called program.exe and it's finding its own process.**

Thanks, i was using the same name to my exe. It work now.